# Can I play Metin2 on Ubuntu?

Tags: games

I want to know if the game Metin2 can be played on Ubuntu because I want to get rid of Windows wich I use only for this game.

Answer (score 1):

Nope.

They have a [Linux page in their Wiki](http://wiki.metin2.co.uk/index.php/Guide%3aInstallation_Linux) but it's ancient. The [recent reviews on Wine's AppDB](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=5201) suggest it just won't play at all [due to an anti-cheat mechanism](http://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4666).

I'm afraid that would also rule out trying to play it in a VirtualBox (et al) Virtual machine (which uses patched DirectX files for Wine to port 3D instructions through to the VM).

Answer (score 0):

there are other official server, for eg. Metin2.sg where there is only server-side anit cheat mechanism so you can play there :D

Answer (score 0):

You can play a few clients which are metin2 sg, metin2 pl or which is do not support hackshield. Or you can play on a PVP server. :)

I have played the german version of this game 2009 with Ubuntu. Today you can play also if you can bypass hackshield. Otherwise you can play a few clients.